# Importing svg into vue3

Tags: typescript, svg, vuejs3

I have the following component:

```
<template>
  <span class="iconDynamic" v-html="data.icon"></span>
</template>
<script lang="ts">
  import { defineComponent, ref } from "vue";
  import svgPlaceholder from '../icons/svg/placeholder.svg';
  import svgHelp from '../icons/svg/help.svg';

  export default defineComponent({
    name: 'DynamicIcon',
    setup() {
      const data = ref({
        icon: ""
      });
      return {
        data,
      };
    },
    mounted(): void {
```

There's code in mounted that sets data.icon = svgPlaceholder or svgHelp (later there will be more). I was expecting it to load the contents of the svg files. However, it renders as:

```
<span class="iconDynamic">/mySite.com/src/icons/svg/placeholder.svg</span>
```

I need these loaded inline so that they can be styled.

Answer (score -1):

you want to set the `src` of an image with the path

```
<span class="iconDynamic">
    <img :src="data.icon" />
</span>
```

and just a quick note about

```
const data = ref({
    icon: ""
});
```

don't instanciate the value with en empty string, it will cause you typings problems later because `svgPlaceholder` is not a string, set it to `null` instead

Comment: I don't want to set the src, because in order to style it, it has to be inline, which is mentioned at the end of the OP

Comment: Ok sorry, I didn't understood what inline meant for you.